# Unable to read NTAG216 for some period

Tags: android, nfc, nxp-microcontroller

After reading a NTAG216 on Android device, the tag could no longer be read. Nothing signal of tag was fired on another devices (tested in 3 android devices).

The weird thing: After some hours (nearly 12 hours), the tag started working again.

Notes:
1) Tag was previously read/wrote just 3 ou 4 times (it's a new tag)
2) Isn't the first time this happens. We have 13 another situations like this. It's a large number of ocurrences, considering we have about 3,000 tags/30,000 reads/writes.

Is this some lock feature? Or a factory defect?

Comment: Since the tag doesn't know any notion of time beyond a single activation, there's no way it could do time-based tarpitting like this. Just pure speculation: Broken antennas maybe that make tags work/fail depending on how you touch them?

Comment: Happens to me another time today. Tried to "fold" tag, but unsucessful.

Comment: I never seen this with another tag types (Mifare, NTAG203, etc...). 
I tried to tap with different positions but unsuccessful too.
And after some hours, the tag turn back to work again